# Text-to-speech on Windows: can I somehow to "cut" that functionality and synthesize THE SAME voice on Linux?

Tags: windows, aws-lambda, azure-functions, text-to-speech

I know that we can use AWS Polly, IBM Watson, Microsoft Cognitive Service or Google Cloud voices, but just curious, for example we can compile Go code for Windows or Linux - is it possible somehow to compile C# that uses `SpVoice` for Linux? As I know neither Mono nor Azure Functions did not have a module for text to speech. Linux subsystem is also not an option - I hope to synthesize voice on AWS Lambdas.

Comment: If a voice sounds in the cloud, will it be heard? And why would you think that a Windows subsystem would run on AWS, which AFAIK doesn't host anything on Windows?

Comment: @CodeCaster it is possible to save WAV on Windows. Yes AWS Lambdas runs on Amazon Linux, but maybe exists some possibility to cut part of Windows...